# Office.mailbox.item.saveAsync takes some time before the item is actually synced to the Exchange server

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Is there any way to check if the Mail item is completely synced with Exchange Online when `Office.mailbox.item.saveAsync` is called for Outlook cached mode?

We are building an Outlook Plugin which is supported for all Outlook environments. We are adding attachments to the compose pane via add `Office.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync` and sending the mail using graph API. But as per the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messagecompose?view=outlook-js-1.4&preserve-view=true#saveAsync_options__callback_),

> For compose add-ins, be aware that when Outlook is in cached mode, it may take some time before the item is actually synced to the server.

As we are sending mail from graph API, we want to make sure that all the attachments have been synced with the server before mail is sent to avoid data loss.

Can someone help with this?

Comment: Just reiterating your query/process.
1. Attaching an attachment using the addFileAttachmentAsync
2. Send the email via the graph APIs 

Is that the correct sequence?

Comment: Yes, It is working fine for OWA, But I am facing a problem in Mac Outlook Cached mode.

Comment: Hey @Mandar_K, Unfortunately, this is the expected behaviour in this scenario, as we can't guarentee the attachments being synced to the server in Outlook in cached mode, and it's clear in the documentation too. Can we know your specific scenario where you need all attachments to be synced before you send an email?